# Does constructing beautification buildings have any in-game effect?

Tags: anno-1404

In Anno 1404, there are quite of few beautification buildings that the computer players use to great effect.  While they are nice, I have better things to spend my resources on if these buildings have no pay-off.

Other than looking nice, does building beautification structures, streets, and parks have any effect?

Comment: I should think that streets would make your city more efficient...

Comment: @GnomeSlice: there are beautification variations of the standard streets.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Those buildings have absolutely no effect, only build them if you care about how your city looks.

Comment: There is one exception: trees. They cost only 5 gold and are available from the beginning. If you place a building which requires trees (lumberjack, charcoal burner, etc.), trees are automatically placed if they are not present. However, if part of the area of your building is outside of your warehouse range, trees are not automatically planted. If you later conquer that territory, you either have to pay close to 1000 gold to automatically plant trees if your building is below 100%, or you can manually place a few cheap trees to bring it up to 100%.